# how to insert an image into code from tailblocks

Tags: html

I'm having trouble trying to change the image in code that i copied from tailblocks, i want to change it to an image file but do not know how to, help would be appreciated as i am just getting into web development

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Tailblocks</title>
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header class="text-gray-600 body-font">
    <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
      <a class="flex title-font font-medium items-center text-gray-900 mb-4 md:mb-0">
        <svg xmlns="" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-10 h-10 text-white p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M12 2L2 7l10 5 10-5-10-5zM2 17l10 5 10-5M2 12l10 5 10-5"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="ml-3 text-xl">Tailblocks</span>
      </a>
      <nav class="md:ml-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center">
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">First Link</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Second Link</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Third Link</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Fourth Link</a>
      </nav>
      <button class="inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 border-0 py-1 px-3 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-base mt-4 md:mt-0">Button
        <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-4 h-4 ml-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>
</html>
```